# Road coordinate caching (breaking Google's T&Cs?)

Tags: php, google-maps

We have sets of rough coordinates for a few hundred road routes across the UK.

The waypoints along the routes are often 50 metres apart. This means that when we draw a line through the coordinates (our software limits us to straight lines) they sometimes cut across roads, buildings etc.

The plan is to create a PHP script that will run the coordinates through *something* which will return close, nicely placed road coordinates and insert them into our database, essentially replacing our spread out, 50 metre apart coordinates.

The only technology we've found that can do this is the Google Maps Directions API. If we pass the waypoints along the route, Google can in return give us perfect road route with the coordinates of each step on a particular leg/straight on the route.

We'd go ahead and do this now if we weren't uncertain about this being allowed.

https://developers.google.com/maps/faq

We have read through the Google Maps FAQ and can't find anything about caching the road coordinates. We don't want to do anything that would breach the terms of service as our application heavily relies on other Google APIs and Google Maps itself.

How should we continue? If this is breaking Google's terms of service, couldn't we just randomize the coordinates they return slightly so they're not the same? How could it be proved we've broken them then?

Comment: "How could it be proved we've broken them then?" Well, if this is an online service, by observing that unique (so that they are less likely to be cached) operations on your application generate requests to Google Maps APIs. This is how they caught Bing fetching results from Google.com a couple years ago. Also, although this very post is not a proof of anything, it might still be a red flag for them...

Comment: @StefanoSanfilippo That's fair enough but we're not actually interested in breaking the rules (if we were I wouldn't have posted this), just thought I'd throw it out there to see what people would say... interesting didn't know about the Bing story. I'm actually just more interested in knowing if it's breaking the rules or not which I can't find anywhere in the Google T&C's that it is, they only mention of caching/serving saved static maps images